# The meaning of a quote

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of these words from Captain Bartholomew Roberts's pirate code?

> Every man to be called fairly in turn, by list, on board of prizes because, (over and above their proper share) they were on these occasions allowed a shift of clothes [...]

Namely, *be called ... of prizes*.

*UPDATE:* Another question is *they were* grammar. Is it the subjunctive?

Comment: I think "on board of prizes" would mean "when aboard captured vessels".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few pieces of jargon go into this.

- A "prize" is, in naval terms, [a captured enemy vessel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prize_(law)).
- To be "on board of" or just "on board" simply means to be on a ship. I get the sense that using "of" is a little bit archaic - you'd normally hear "on board the ship", not "on board of the ship" these days - but the meaning is the same.

So, Captain Bartholomew is saying that every man shall be summoned one by one in some equitable order to come aboard (or on board) a captured ship.

Comment: It's a bit off-topic, but how do I parse "they were"? Is it the subjunctive?

Comment: @olegst It's not the subjunctive. I'm not sure exactly what construction it technically is - the grammar is a little archaic I think - but it seems to me to be something like [the habitual aspect](http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/Habitual_aspect). It just means that as a matter of custom, when a prize was taken, each man would be allowed a shift of clothes (I assume as "loot" from the fallen enemy sailors).